# Partial derivative of a function of the form $g(x)=\int_V f(x,y)~dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose $U,V$ are open boxes in $\Bbb R^n$, $\Bbb R^m$, respectively, and $f:U\times V\to \Bbb R$ is continuously differentiable. For $g:U\to \Bbb R$ defined by $g(x)=\int_V f(x,y)~dy$, I am trying to compute $\partial g/\partial x_i$ $(i=1,\dots,n)$. Note that $$ \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} (x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{g(x+he_i)-g(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{1}{h} \int_V f(x+he_i,y)-f(x,y)~dy , $$
so if we can interchange the integral and the limit, we get $\partial g(x)/\partial x_i= \int_V \partial_if (x,y)~dy$. But can we interchange the integral and the limit in this case?

Comment: See theorem 4.4.3 in [this paper](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~richardt/MA2224/MA2224-ch4.pdf#page5). This is easily derived from Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.